# No insertar números repetidos en un array? Javascript

Tags: javascript, array

tengo un array, al que voy metiendo numeros aleatorios del 1 al 50.

Lo que necesito es comparar el siguiente numero con los de dentro del array para evitar que haya alguno repetido.

Tengo esto:

```
//ARRAY con los numeros del 1 al 50
       var aNumeros=[];
       for (let intI =1; intI<=50; intI++)
                aNumeros.push(intI);


//ARRAY EN DONDE QUIERO METER LOS NUMEROS

                  aElegidos.push(aNumeros.splice(parseInt(Math.random()*aNumeros.length), 1));
```

Comment: Hola, no me queda claro cuántos números deben de haber en `aElegidos`. Si es la misma cantidad entonces no importa que algoritmo uses para insertarlos porque finalmente contendrán los mismos números.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias utilizar `inArray` de JQuery, con esto primero verificas si el valor existe en el arreglo, y ya en base a eso tu decides que hacer con ello:

```
var aNumeros=[];
var aElegidos=[];

       for (let intI =1; intI<=50; intI++)
                aNumeros.push(intI);

var elegido = aNumeros.splice(parseInt(Math.random()*aNumeros.length), 1);

     if($.inArray(elegido, aElegidos) == -1){
        aElegidos.push(elegido);
        console.log("no existe");
     } else {
        console.log("existe");
     }
```

Espero y te sirva, y sobre todo haberte entendido. Saludos.

Fuente: [JQuery InArray](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)